# Dynamic html table using Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pug, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to create a dynamic html table using Angular.

The scope has a two-dimensional array (called array) that contains data that is used to generate the table.

Jade:

```
table(class="table table-striped")
    thead
      tr
        th
          | Header
    tbody
      div(ng-controller="indexCtrl")
        tr(ng-repeat="row in array")
          td(class="row")
            div(ng-repeat="cell in row", class="col-md-6")
              .checkbox
                label
                  input(type="checkbox",name="{{cell.permission}}")
                    | {{cell.name}}
```

The result I want is:

x box1  x box2

x box3  x box4

At the moment, only the table head is generated. No rows. What is wrong with my template?

Comment: there is probably no variable called array in the scope

Comment: Did you inject your rows into $scope.array from your code behind?

Comment: are there any errors? can we see `indexCtrl`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `table` must have there own element like `td`, `tr`, `th`, `tbody`,
>   etc. If you want to place other element in `table`, you could have it in `td` /`th` only

You should place `ng-controller` on `tbody` element.

`table` doesn't allow other elements in it like you placed `div` in `tbody`

```
table(class="table table-striped")
    thead
      tr
        th
          | Header
    tbody(ng-controller="indexCtrl")
        tr(ng-repeat="row in array")
          td(class="row")
            div(ng-repeat="cell in row", class="col-md-6")
              .checkbox
                label
                  input(type="checkbox",name="{{cell.permission}}")
                    | {{cell.name}}
```

Comment: Just a side note. `table` also allows for multiple occurrences of the `<tbody>` element as well. For things like grouping.